# Is it possible to override one part of a control template in a Telerik WPF theme?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, telerik, themes

I am using the Telerik Windows 8 theme in my WPF application.  However, I do not like the way the checkbox checked state is indicated using a colored square rather than an actual checkmark as in the Windows 7 theme.  It was very simple to copy the checkbox template and modify it to use the checkbox checkmark from the Windows 7 theme checkbox template.

However, I am having trouble finding a way to add the style that contains this modified template to my Application.Resources in such a way as to apply it to all checkboxes in my application.  For some reason, the template in the Telerik Windows 8 theme continues to be the one that is applied.

I have tried a few different approaches, yet nothing seems to work.  My latest approach is to add the following style to my Application.Resources resource dictionary:

`<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {telerik:ThemeResourceKey ThemeType=telerik:Windows8Theme, ElementType=CheckBox}}" TargetType="CheckBox" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
    ....
    </Setter>
</Style>`

Does anyone know the answer to this question?  Is what I am trying to do possible?

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: I've never done it. And I'm pretty sure you've already came across this [How To Apply Custom Style to Controls](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/styling-and-appearance/styling-apperance-implicit-styles-overview#how-to-apply-custom-style-to-controls).

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are ferencing the DLLs from the NoXaml folder of your Telerik install
2. Don't add any reference to any of the Theme DLLs
3. In your Telerik WPF install location, go into Themes.Implicit > WPF40 > Windows8 > Themes
4. Put the .xaml files from there into your solution
5. Reference them in your App.xaml resource dictionary:

   ```
   <Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Office2016/System.Windows.xaml" />
           <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Office2016/Telerik.Windows.Controls.xaml" />
           <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Office2016/Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.xaml" />
    etc...
           </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```
6. Now you can go into the System.Windows.xaml file, and find the style for the checkbox and edit the style to change the square to a tick
   (I think it's the Rectangle called CheckVisual in the Checkbox Template which you need to change)